# How to remove the Div and Content in jQuery for the below HTML

Tags: jquery

On page if I include a hyperlink tag like this:

```
<a href="#">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="placeholder.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

Then jQuery is not removing thumbnail-loader div. I provided the HTML / jQuery what I am using above.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
  <div class="card card-list h-100">
    <div class="card-img thumbnail-loading">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="love-badge text-danger">
          <i class="mdi mdi-heart-outline"></i></a>
      <span class="trust badge-success">CONTENT</span>
      <span class="feature badge-warning">CONTENT</span>
      <span class="badge badge-primary">CONTENT</span>
      <div class="thumbnail-loader">
        <span class="ico ico-spinner-alt-2 ico-rotate"></span>
        <span class="loading-text">Loading</span>
      </div>
      <a href="#">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="placeholder.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="text-primary mb-2 mt-0">
          <a href="#">TITTLE</a> <small></small>
        </h2>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mt-1 mb-0 text-muted"><i class="mdi mdi-currency-usd"></i> <strong></strong></h6>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <span><i class="mdi mdi-thumb-up"></i> <strong></strong></span>
        <span><i class="mdi mdi-thumb-down"></i> <strong></strong></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.thumbnail-loading img').unveil(200, function() {
      $(this).load(function() {
        $(this).prev('.thumbnail-loader').remove();
        $(this).parent().removeClass('thumbnail-loading');
      });
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: Please provide codes, what you have tried, otherwise how someone can help you.

Comment: where is your HTML / Jquery above?

Comment: Where's the jQuery? Also please take care when formatting code in your questions as the HTML was originally unreadable

Comment: @Matrix Please edit your question instead of posting your code in the comment section.

Comment: `<div class="love-badge text-danger">` is not closed in your given code. seems like invalid html created. (however modern browsers close them automatically)

Comment: `$(this).prev('.thumbnail-loader').remove();` needs to be `$(this).children('.thumbnail-loader').remove();` or `$(this).find('.thumbnail-loader').remove();`

Comment: @Matrix  you have to create a working example of your current problem. either use stack overflow code editor itself or use jsfiddle for that. add the working link in your question. that will help you to get solution quickly.

Comment: I got working if I hyperlink the thumbnail-loader div too as below <a href="#">
        <div class="thumbnail-loader">
        <span class="ico ico-spinner-alt-2 ico-rotate"></span>
        <span class="loading-text">Loading</span>
      </div>
      <img class="card-img-top" src="placeholder.jpg" alt="">
      </a> Thank you all!! :)